# Not getting access token via login with Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using login with facebook in android. But i am not getting access token .
I am getting user details like email , name, etc .
Could any please tell me that why i am not getting token?

i am using facebook sdk 4.0.0.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends     Activity {
        private CallbackManager callbackManager;
        private LoginButton loginButton;
        private TextView btnLogin;
        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        private AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker;
        private ProfileTracker profileTracker;

        private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> callback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
                String token = loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken();
                Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                displayMessage(profile);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {

            }
        };

        User user;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this);
            callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

            accessTokenTracker= new AccessTokenTracker() {
                @Override
                protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldToken, AccessToken newToken) {

                }
            };

            profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
                @Override
                protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile newProfile) {
                    displayMessage(newProfile);
                }
            };

            accessTokenTracker.startTracking();
            profileTracker.startTracking();
            AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            assert getActionBar() != null;
            getActionBar().hide();

            if(PrefUtils.getCurrentUser(MainActivity.this) != null){
                //Intent homeIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LogoutActivity.class);
                Intent homeIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListViewActivity.class);
                startActivity(homeIntent);
                finish();
            }
            /*try {
                PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                        "com.comida",
                        PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
                for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                    md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                    Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
                }
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

            }*/
           /* FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();
                }
            });*/
        }


        private void displayMessage(Profile profile){
            if(profile != null){
                //textView.setText(profile.getName());
            }
        }

   @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();



            callbackManager=CallbackManager.Factory.create();

            loginButton= (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);

            loginButton.setReadPermissions("public_profile", "email","user_friends");

            btnLogin= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
            btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                    progressDialog.show();

                    loginButton.performClick();

                    loginButton.setPressed(true);

                    loginButton.invalidate();

                    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, mCallBack);

                    loginButton.setPressed(false);

                    loginButton.invalidate();

                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }


        private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> mCallBack = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

                progressDialog.dismiss();

                // App code
                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                        //loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                        AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(
                                    JSONObject object,
                                    GraphResponse response) {

                                Log.e("response: ", response + "");
                                try {
                                    user = new User();
                                    user.facebookID = object.getString("id").toString();
                                    user.email = object.getString("email").toString();
                                    user.name = object.getString("name").toString();
                                    user.gender = object.getString("gender").toString();
                                    PrefUtils.setCurrentUser(user,MainActivity.this);

                                }catch (Exception e){
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"welcome "+user.name,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ListViewActivity.class);
                                //Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,LogoutActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();

                            }

                        });

                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender, birthday");
                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();
            }

            @Override
            public void     onCancel() {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        };

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        /*@Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }*/
    }
```

Logcat

```
08-05 16:08:17.964 2258-2829/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/Auth: [GoogleAccountDataServiceImpl] getToken() -> BAD_AUTHENTICATION. Account: <ELLIDED:601871123>, App: com.google.android.gms, Service: oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/games
                                                                       dkq: Long live credential not available.
                                                                           at dkr.a(:com.google.android.gms:3101)
                                                                           at dje.a(:com.google.android.gms:397)
                                                                           at djd.a(:com.google.android.gms:31369)
                                                                           at djd.a(:com.google.android.gms:313)
                                                                           at elb.a(:com.google.android.gms:1201)
                                                                           at ela.a(:com.google.android.gms:530)
                                                                           at ela.a(:com.google.android.gms:196)
                                                                           at dfw.a(:com.google.android.gms:320)
                                                                           at dfw.a(:com.google.android.gms:210)
                                                                           at dgf.a(:com.google.android.gms:1498)
                                                                           at dge.a(:com.google.android.gms:909)
                                                                           at dge.e(:com.google.android.gms:523)
                                                                           at dgd.a(:com.google.android.gms:37)
                                                                           at dhm.getAuthToken(:com.google.android.gms:178)
                                                                           at android.accounts.AbstractAccountAuthenticator$Transport.getAuthToken(AbstractAccountAuthenticator.java:214)
                                                                           at android.accounts.IAccountAuthenticator$Stub.onTransact(IAccountAuthenticator.java:113)
                                                                           at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)

08-05 16:08:18.040 2258-2829/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/GLSActivity: dgt: BadAuthentication
                                                                                  at dgf.a(:com.google.android.gms:1515)
                                                                                  at dge.a(:com.google.android.gms:909)
                                                                                  at dge.e(:com.google.android.gms:523)
                                                                                  at dgd.a(:com.google.android.gms:37)
                                                                                  at dhm.getAuthToken(:com.google.android.gms:178)
                                                                                  at android.accounts.AbstractAccountAuthenticator$Transport.getAuthToken(AbstractAccountAuthenticator.java:214)
                                                                                  at android.accounts.IAccountAuthenticator$Stub.onTransact(IAccountAuthenticator.java:113)
                                                                                  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
```

Comment: Please slim down your question to only include the relevant code, not dozens of imports, non-important methods, commented-out code blocks.

Comment: Have you tried to Log the accessToken? I think you are just not using it. You have it but you don't use it.

Comment: If you are getting user details, then you must have an access token – otherwise the API would not give you those in the first place.

Comment: I have shown logcat now

Comment: String token = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getToken(); by replace String token = loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken();

Answer (score 0):

You can get the token by using

```
AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getToken();
```

Using this you can get the token at any time, if you use the LoginResult, you get it only once at the time you log in, when you restart the app the onSuccess is not called.

If you need the profile after restarting, you use

```
Profile.getCurrentProfile();
```

If this returns null you are not loged in

Comment: i have used but did not get .

Comment: You can store access token in like
String  token = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getToken(); @user6313669

Comment: you wrote in  FacebookCallback<LoginResult> method ??

Comment: where i should write ?

Comment: in onSuccess of  private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> callback method

Comment: I have written but did not get & updating logcat what i am getting .

Comment: what you getting in access token ?

Comment: yesterday i have used and it is working perfect for me so try my friend !!!

Comment: Please see logcat what i am getting warning and all but not getting ? can you provide me your code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120228/discussion-between-vishal-patoliya-and-user6313669).

Comment: if you are not getting access token from facebook than you can manage it by device token of android

Answer (score 0):

You have the access token but you never use it directly.

If you want for example to log the user's ID through the token you could :

```
Log.w("accessToken", accessToken.getUserId().toString());
```

As @Cbroe mentioned in a comment, which is right :

> If you are getting user details, then you must have an access token –
>   otherwise the API would not give you those in the first place.

Comment: Actually i want to store access token with user details for particular user who is going to login with facebook . If i cant get directly then how can i store in data base .?